# d.ts enum values don't end up in the compiled output

Tags: typescript, webpack-5, babel-loader, ts-loader

I have a project where I have a big global.d.ts file.
the project runs on webpack 4 + typescript 4 and uses the awesome-typescript-loader and babel-loader.
The project is pretty old basically.
I am setting the project with webpack 5, typescript 5 and esbuild-loader.

Inside, I have a couple of enums such as

```
declare enum MyEnum {
   propertyOne = 'value1',
   propertyTwo = 'value2',
   //... etc
}
```

When the enum is outputted inside the compiled code, it looks like this:

```
[
   MyEnum.propertyOne,
   MyEnum.propertyTwo,
   //... etc
]
```

While i would expect MyEnum.propertyOne and MyEnum.propertyTwo to be both their respective values, 'value1' and 'value2'.

Meaning i'd expect this:

```
[
   'value1',
   'value2',
   //... etc
]
```

In my tsconfig I have the following properties set to true:

```
declaration: true,
preserveConstEnums: true,
isolatedModules: true
```

Besides, the global.d.ts file is included in the "include" array and inside "typeRoots" array.

I have also tried setting the enums to const.

```
declare const enum MyEnum {
   propertyOne = 'value1',
   propertyTwo = 'value2',
   //... etc
}
```

I have also tried ts-loader, which does compile the code properly only if it isn't supplied with the transpileOnly option set to true, however it is very slow.

I was wondering if there was some kind of trick to make esbuild-loader work in this way or in a similar way, just to not make the code break and remain performant enough.

I have also attempted to try babel-loader, but it has the same issue.

If fixing this can't be achieved with either esbuild-loader or babel-loader I was wondering if there are other loaders out there that work similarly to ts-loader while being performant?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to remove `declare` from where you used `const`:

```
const enum MyEnum {
   propertyOne = 'value1',
   propertyTwo = 'value2',
   //... etc
}
```

Comment: It says: TypeScript Error: Top-level declarations in .d.ts files must start with either a 'declare' or 'export' modifier.

I tried to remove the .d.ts extension and substitute it with .ts after which it didn't complain anymore, but that didn't help in making the enum compile.

Comment: I am going to accept this as an answer, because it's a part of what I did. I decided to move the enums to a .ts file and import them where they are needed. Now the compiler doesn't break, although the values aren't inlined the values are accessed through a webpack property. I am a bit unhappy about it, but it is what it is.